# Laravel 10.45 - Enum validation - Unable to set custom message

Tags: laravel, validation, enums

I'm not able to add a custom validation message for enum rules.

I have my rule defined as:

```
'components.*.component_type' => ['required', Rule::enum(BlueprintComponentType::class)]
```

The custom message is defined as:

```
'custom' => [ 'components.*.component_type' => [ 'enum' => 'The component type field should be ...', ], ],
```

The output is "The selected components.0.component_type is invalid" which is the value for validation.enum

Later edit:

I tried to debug, directly inside the framework classes and I noticed something strange:

dump(__('validation.custom'));

```
    array:3 [ // vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Enum.php:67
      "attribute-name" => array:1 [
        "rule-name" => "custom-message"
      ]
      "user_id" => array:1 [
        "exists" => "User #:input not found"
      ]
      "components.*.component_type" => array:2 [
        "enum" => "The component type field can be: text, textarea, select, checkbox, radio, image"
        "in" => "The component type field can be: text, textarea, select, checkbox, radio, image"
      ]

dump(__('validation.custom.components.*.component_type')

    "validation.custom.components.*.component_type" // vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Enum.php:68

lang/validation.php

    'custom' => [
        'user_id' => [
            'exists' => 'User #:input not found',
        ],
//        'components' => [
//            'required' => 'Provide at least one blueprint component',
//        ],
//        'components.*.name' => [
//            'required' => 'Each component must have a name value',
//        ],
//        'components.*.description' => [
//            'required' => 'Each component must have a description value',
//        ],
//        'components.*.info' => [
//            'string' => 'The component info field must be a string',
//        ],
        'components.*.component_type' => [
            'enum' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
            'in' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            '\App\Enums\BlueprintComponentType' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            '/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Enum' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            '\Illuminate\Validatio\Rules\Enum' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            'Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            'App\Enums\BlueprintComponentType' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
//            'Illuminate\\Validation\\Rules\\Enum' => 'The component type field can be: '.BlueprintComponentType::listKeys(),
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `in` rule instead, because `enum` is essentially shorthand for the `in` rule.

```
'custom' => [
    'components.*.component_type' => [
        'in' => 'The component type field should be ...',
    ],
],
```

If the above code doesn't work try defining this in FormRequest

```
public function messages()
{
  return [
    "components.*.component_type.Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum" => "The component type field should be ..."
  ];
}
```

---

Comment: I tried with `in` ..and also with `/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Enum.php` and `\App\Enums\BlueprintComponentType` ..it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you define it in Form Request function `messages()`?

Comment: With the messages method added in the Request, I'm getting back the error message. I don't understand why I can't use the lang variable though

Comment: Can you show how you defined it and how are you trying to use lang variable?

Comment: I added more info in the original question. Thx